# How to upload dev build to apple test flight with diffrent bundle id

Tags: ios

Because of incompatible changes on the backend I want to upload my app with a diffrent namespace and config to testflight for internal testing. I dont want to publish this version.

The production namespace is `de.domain.app` and dev is `de.domain.app.dev`.
How can I publish the dev version in testflight?

Do I have to create a completely new app in app store?

Comment: You need the AppStore bundle id in TestFlight : when a build in TestFlight seems good, you can publish it to AppStore without uploading it again.  A version in TestFlight does not have to go to AppStore and be reviewed.

Comment: So i have to create a new app for each bundle id?

Comment: You need to keep same bundle if if you plan to have this version replace the older one in AppStore in some future.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you need an additional app on App Store connect.  The bundle id is the thing that identifies an app. We do this. We have our released app and we have our internal "preview" release in App Store connect.  The second app never gets published to the store. It only gets distributed internally via TestFlight.